# Why is background image not working in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to import a jpg image and use it as background image. However, it is not working. No image is being shown on background. [Note that the image is fine, and the import is fine. I have tried using img tag].

```
import login_bg from './Login.jpg'
<div style = {{backgroundImage: `url(${login_bg})`, backgroundPosition: 'center',
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}>
HII
  </div>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: try giving some padding to the div, you will see the image if the image is correct.

Comment: If you're using a react project which was created using create-react-app, move the image into the public folder and call the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing with some problems with importing images. You can easily use an image url and paste is inside of that url(). I hope it solves your problem.